# Syncadapter for more than one account type

Tags: android, android-manifest, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

Is it possible to have a syncadapter for several account-types? (e.g. com.google and com.facebook.auth.login)

It seems the syncadapter.xml just accepts a single value like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.foo"
    android:accountType="com.google"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

I want to have several account options available for my users like google, facebook and twitter.

Comment: I didn't got it. why you try to use several account-types?  account-type don't relate to server address. could you more explain?

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation for [AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) uses plural (emphasis added), see

> The android:contentAuthority and android:accountType attributes indicate which content authority and for which account **types** this sync adapter serves.

I don't think it supports that. I'm not fully sure, but it looks like [this is the code for how the sync-adapter xml is parsed](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/SyncAdaptersCache.java). I expected some loop to split the accountType attribute into multiple types if it had support for that:

```
 79     static class MySerializer implements XmlSerializerAndParser<SyncAdapterType> {
 80         public void writeAsXml(SyncAdapterType item, XmlSerializer out) throws IOException {
 81             out.attribute(null, "authority", item.authority);
 82             out.attribute(null, "accountType", item.accountType);
 83         }
 84 
 85         public SyncAdapterType createFromXml(XmlPullParser parser)
 86                 throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
 87             final String authority = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "authority");
 88             final String accountType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "accountType");
 89             return SyncAdapterType.newKey(authority, accountType);
 90         }
```

However, maybe it is possible to add one XML for each account type you support but refer to the same content authority?

Comment: that would require several services since the meta-data tag is included in the service-tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Indeed. Looking at the code for initializeSyncAdapter <http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/SyncManager.java#401> I doubt Android was designed to handle this scenario. It seems to assume that a SyncAdapter has a one-to-one relationship with a specific account type. Maybe your best bet is to create a custom account type and use OAuth to let users reuse their accounts at OAuth service providers.